# ubuntu-mate for Raspberry Pi file system capacity 100% used

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-mate

really new into ubuntu. I am using raspberryi pi 2 with ubuntu-mate. I have 16GB sd card, but i get error now that my total file system capacity is full.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       3,5G  3,5G  392K 100% /
devtmpfs        459M     0  459M   0% /dev
tmpfs           463M  368K  463M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           463M  6,8M  457M   2% /run
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1   64M   20M   45M  31% /boot
tmpfs            93M   48K   93M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Edit:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0     179:0    0 14,7G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   64M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  3,6G  0 part /




Model: SD SD16G (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 15,7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1      1049kB  68,2MB  67,1MB  primary  fat16        boot, lba
2      68,2MB  3932MB  3864MB  primary  ext4
```

Comment: Edit your post to include the output of `lsblk` and `sudo parted -l`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looks like your root partition is of only 3.5GB and that your root partition is not using all of your 16Gb space. You need to resize your root so that it will use all of your card's space.

Plug in the Pi's sd-card to your computer/laptop and resize it using gparted( [youtube video to show you how](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_jNL0mmaLQ) )

Remember you have to only resize the second partition i.e. root `mmcblk0p2` or remember it is `ext4` formatted and is of 3.5Gb size

OR

You can do that while you are in Ubuntu-mate but it requires little expert since it will be pure command line.

from official website [docs](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/)

There are no utilities included for automatic file system re-sizing. However, it’s not hard to do manually. Once booted:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0
```

Delete the second partition (d, 2), then re-create it using the defaults (n, p, 2, enter, enter), then write and exit (w). Reboot the system, then:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2
```